# frequency of data updates in source system

Tags: openfda

Is the source database for OpenFDA APIs updated on real time with the updates released by FDA?
If not, what is the ideal update frequency, particularly for medical devices recalls and classification.

Answer (score 1):

No, openFDA isn't being updated in real time. Device Recall and Device Classification endpoints are updated weekly.